# Linking fields on Power BI

Tags: powerbi

very new to Power, so sorry for asking a silly question.

I've got one table with required skills for a particular role, and a second table with a list of users and self-assessment for each of those skills.

Table1 has a 2 columns [Question] and [Required Score]
Table2 has 3 columns: [User], [Question] and [Score]

I'm trying to write a DAX formula to use as a filter: I want to return only those users where their own score is equal to or greater than the required minimum.

My current Measure is: `= Table1[Question] = Table2[Question] && Table1[Required Score] <= Table2[Score]`

Ask I'm typing the formula:

- the tables are not being recognised
- all [fields] are underlined in red
- error message "A single value for column 'Question' in table 'Table1' cannot be determined.

Table1[Question] and Table2[Question] Data type = text, Format = Text, Summarization = Don't summarize, Data Category = Uncategorized

Table1[Required Score] and Table2[Score] Data type = Fixed decimal number, Format = Decimal number, Summarization = Don't summarize, Data category = Uncategorized

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and point me in the direction of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tables, I'd do the following

1. In your Relationships, link the Question column, in Table1 & Table2
2. In DAX, add a new column to Table2; the formula will be something
   like: Score >= RELATED(RequiredScore) i.e. a Boolean
3. In your visual, filter Table2 on this new column = True